# Python- can't connect to my IP

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

I started learning about computer networks and I tried using sockets in Python.
With a little help from a youtube video, I made a very simple Chatting program between a Server and a Client.
When I tried to connect the client with 'localhost', it worked just the way I wanted. But when I tried using the IP address (that I found on findmyip.org, for example lets say 12.123.12.123), It just didn't show any sign of a connection.
The Server is:

```
import socket
import sys

def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''
        port = 9998
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print "socket creation error bluhbluh"
    print "socket created"

def socket_bind():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        print "Binding socket to port"
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msk:
        print "socket binding error"
        socket_bind()


def socket_accept():
    conn,address = s.accept()
    print "connection has been established"
    print address[0]
    send_msg(conn)
    conn.close()

def send_msg(conn):
    while 1:
        mess=raw_input()
        if mess == "quit":
            conn.send(mess)
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(mess)>0:
            conn.send(mess)
            resp=conn.recv(1024)
            print resp

def main():
    socket_create()
    socket_bind()
    socket_accept()

main()
```

The Client is:

```
import socket
import os
import sys

s = socket.socket()
host = '12.123.12.123' #replace with 'localhost' for a working version! :D 
port = 9998
s.connect((host,port))

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print data
    if data=="quit":
        s.close()
    else:
        mess=raw_input()
        s.send(mess)
```

I Had this problem before, and from what I can remember, I didn't manage to fix it then aswell..
I tried port forwarding (at least I THINK I did it right)
I hope you could help me
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: "*I tried port forwarding (at least I THINK I did it right)*" - connecting from inside your network to the outside address and being forwarded back in, requires special support on the firewall/router. It's often called 'hairpin NAT' or 'loopback NAT'. If you have a basic home device, it might not support doing that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is likely related to the network. The IP you posted is what is called a routable IP, the IP exposed to the internet. It normally gets assigned to the WAN side of your ISP provided modem or a router. Machines like your PC will normally live on the LAN side of the network device and will likely be assigned a non-routable IP, these cannot be seen from the internet.

When you go to a site that shows your IP it is showing your routable IP, not the one the network device assigned to your machine. To see that address you can type 'ipconfig' in a command window on Windows or 'ifconfig' in a terminal shell on linux and mac. You should see in that output a list of one or more interfaces which contain IP addresses. One will likely have the address of 127.0.0.1 which is equal to localhost and is known as your loopback address. You may see another one starting with 10. or 192. . That address is likely the one assigned to you by the network device. You can try that address and see if your program works.

Comment: I tried the 192. and it DID work. But in case I would like to send this client to a friend living far away, which IP do I need to put in? the routable IP? the non-routable IP?

Comment: So, there are a few ways to do this and it takes a bit of understanding of how to configure your network device. The best approach I would suggest is to use port forwarding. How to configure it depends on your device. Essentially, what a port forward will do is say any traffic addressed to the WAN IP A on port X redirect it to LAN IP B on port Y. It will expose that port on your machine to the internet but only that port you assign. Depending on how you wrote the program this may have to be done on both sides.

Comment: Okay so I used the routable IP with a friend and I port-forwarded it and It worked. thank you! :)